# Apache2 apparently not working

Tags: apache-httpd

First off, I am on Raspberry Pi B+, and I have just changed its IP address to static. Since I just changed the IP address to static, I go to my browser and type my Raspberry Pi's IP address, which I know for a fact, which I'll just say is `180.360.1.1`.

So, I have my Raspberry Pi all powered up, and then I go to my browser and type in `180.360.1.1`. However, it just sort of doesn't 'register', or doesn't have any results, so it just shows my internet provider, and list of website suggestions as usual when there is not a result.

Any help? It's been working until now. I used this tutorial: [How To Assign A Static IP to The Raspberry Pi](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Assign-A-Static-IP-to-The-Raspberry-Pi/).

Comment: Is that the real address you used? because there is no such IP address.

Comment: If that isn't the real address, you might as well use the real one.  It's on a LAN, no one can reach it anyway and if they cracked through the router they could find everything.  You are not keeping any meaningful secret.  WRT your problem, have a look here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921 -> It is probably more authoritative than the "instructable".

Comment: I would always try first of all to log in on the raspberry and try to load the web page from localhost (using e.g. lynx or wget) - if you get something reasonable there, you will know the problem has to do With the networking, if it doesn't work from localhost, the problem is (probably) in the Apache setup. You can also look in the Apache logs if there is any errors and to see if your accesses to the server are registered at all-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to assign a private address to your apache server. You do however, have to assign an address that is *reachable* from the web browsing client. If you give the apache server an address on the same subnet as your web browsing client, apache would be reachable.

You can test if the apache server is reachable by going to the command line on your client and typing: ping 180.180.1.1 . (180.360.1.1… not a valid IPv4 address.)

It seems that your web browser is not forming the http request properly. Typically, you see a web page from your internet provider and a list of website suggestions only when a DNS query fails. You should not see that when entering an IP address.

Try entering the full path in the address bar:

http://180.180.1.1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a private IP address starting from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.0.254`. Choose one and attach it to your raspberry. Then it should work.